# How to setup and test hangfire with Azure AD

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0, hangfire

In reference to this question:
[.NET Core WebApi Secure Hangfire Dashboard with Azure AD Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949364/net-core-webapi-secure-hangfire-dashboard-with-azure-ad-login)

I have implemented hangfire with an azure AD Authentication for the hangfire dashboard, like jarodsmk answers in the question above.

I have a frontend that logs the user into azure b2c and I'm hosting hangfire on the backend API.

I'm not sure how to test this hangfire dashboard authentication. Attaching the bearer token that I receive from MSAL on the front-end doesn't work and I just receive 401 Unauthorized.

This is how I've setup hangfire and also the same order of execution:

```
public static void AddB2CAuthorisation(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
    }
    
    public static void AddHangfireAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HangfireAzureAdPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
    }

 public static void AddHangfire(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddHangfire(config => config
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBConnectionString")));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
    }
```

in program file:

```
 app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.AddHangfireRoute(); // rest of this is below
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

```
public static IEndpointRouteBuilder AddHangfireRoute(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Dashboard Name",
                Authorization = new []
                {
                    new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter()
                }
            })
            .RequireAuthorization("HangfireAzureAdPolicy"); // Matches your policy name in Auth
        return endpoints;
    }
```

The extra Authorization Filter:

```
public class HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
        return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Lastly this is how the app settings are structured

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": ""
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "TenantId": ""
  },
```

Deployed the API and tested on the server: domain/hangfire
Tested with a MSAL generated bearer token and attached it as an authorization bearer header to the same route as above

Answer (score 0):

Issue is caused by using app.UseHangfireDashboard(); before calling endpoints.AddHangfireRoute();
It voids the second method that is called and configuration is not applied